# Error: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls. in Page Layout SharePoint 2016

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have SharePoint error in custom page layout its Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls

And I checked this issue in SP logs here

```
Error=Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.  
 at System.Web.UI.FileLevelPageControlBuilder.AppendLiteralString(String text)    
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessLiteral()
```

[Error Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B2Gf.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution it's just Change the placeholder content tag from `<asp:content>` to `<asp:Content>` in your Page Layout and it will works fine